# How to access elements by class with CKEditor 4?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I am building a plugin for CK-Editor and having trouble accessing span elements by their class name.

I've added the javascript commands to the plugin, but they aren't working. And when I try the same in the browser console, I get an empty array returned.

The span looks like the following:

```
<span class="rk_section" name="gXVyh" tags="test">UNITED STATES</span>
```

... and I've also tried the following directly in the browser console:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('rk_section')

CKEDITOR.document.find('.rk_section')
```

Both return empty arrays.

I'm baffled why this isn't working.

Comment: You should add more code to create a working snippet. :) When do your JS execute? Are you sure the `rk_section` exists when it's executed?

Comment: Are you sure the span is in the DOM when you click the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a CKEditor instance named `editor1`:

```
CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.document.$.getElementsByClassName('rk_section')
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to modify it a little bit for my situation, but this helped a lot.   For my specific situation, because CK Editor is loaded through a Django package, I used: `CKEDITOR.instances.id_document_rich_body.document.$.getElementsByClassName('rk_section')` For anyone landing here because of `django-ckeditor`, the `id_document_rich_body` refers to the model name and field name.